# Making a Login with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to make a basic login screen with PHP but when I want to check the password with a foreach loop, It won't work. I made an array to save a few usernames and passwords and want to check it with a foreach loop and if you signed in, you should get a message which shows you if you're signed in or not.
I think the part that is not working is the foreach loop but in my eyes, it should work.

I hope anybody can help me with this problem. Already thanks for the time.
PHP:

```
    //message variable aanmaken
    $message = "";
    $succes = false;

// "Database" met usernames en wachtwoorden
$Data["Matthijs123"] = "ikwilbinnen";
$Data["MatthijsHulshof"] = "Eindopdracht123";
$Data["Login"] = "Password";
$Data["123"] = "456";
/*$Data[""] = "";
$Data[""] = "";
$Data[""] = "";
$Data[""] = "";
$Data[""] = "";
$Data[""] = "";
*/
// Check of $_POST minimaal 1 item heeft
if(count($_POST) >= 1)
{
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];



    // Checken of de opgegeven username en wachtwoord in de $data array zit
    foreach($Data as $index => $value)
    {
        if($username == $index && $password == $value)
        {
            //Wachtwoord en username combinatie gevonden!
            $succes = true;
        }
        else
        {
           $succes = false;
        }
    }
    if($succes == true)
    {
        $message = "U bent ingelogd";
    }
    else
    {
        $message = "U wachtwoord en / of gebruikersnaam is fout";
    }
}


?>
```

HTML:

```
        <form action="Login.php" method="post">
            <table id="login">
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">Bergheen</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">Login om adresgegevens + openingstijden te zien.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><?php echo $message; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Username:</td>
                    <td><input name="Username" type="text" placeholder="Username"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td>
                    <td><input name="Password" type="password" placeholder="Password"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><button>Login</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working, but there are two errors, as you have to use $_POST as $_POST['Username'] instead of $_POST['username'] and same in Password too. Cause you have defined the name of input in form. 
   For checking what $_POST values you are getting you can use print_r($_POST) on page. 
   And you want to alert if login is done so use Some html or javascript code to print or alert your message variable.

Here is a code that alerts on success

```
<?php

 //message variable aanmaken
 $message = "";
 $succes = false;

 // "Database" met usernames en wachtwoorden
 $Data["Matthijs123"] = "ikwilbinnen";
 $Data["MatthijsHulshof"] = "Eindopdracht123";
 $Data["Login"] = "Password";
 $Data["123"] = "456";
 /*$Data[""] = "";
 $Data[""] = "";
 $Data[""] = "";
  $Data[""] = "";
  $Data[""] = "";
  $Data[""] = "";
  */
     // Check of $_POST minimaal 1 item heeft
    if(count($_POST) >= 1)
    {

     $username = @$_POST["Username"];
     $password = @$_POST["Password"];



       // Checken of de opgegeven username en wachtwoord in de $data array zit
      foreach($Data as $index => $value)
     {
       echo "<br>".$index;
       echo "<br>".$value;
      if($username == $index && $password == $value)
      {
        //Wachtwoord en username combinatie gevonden!
        $succes = true;

        echo "<script>window.alert('success');</script>";
    }
    else
    {
       $succes = false;
    }
}
if($succes == true)
{
    $message = "U bent ingelogd";
}
else
{
    $message = "U wachtwoord en / of gebruikersnaam is fout";
}
}


?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Whats happening is that it's continuing to compare the user name and password all the way through the array.  This means it will only ever be correct for the last entry.  What you should do is once you have found the user, exit the loop (using `break;`)...

```
// Checken of de opgegeven username en wachtwoord in de $data array zit
$succes = false;
foreach($Data as $index => $value)
{
    if($username == $index && $password == $value)
    {
        //Wachtwoord en username combinatie gevonden!
        $succes = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

This code only ever sets `$success=false` at the start, so this won't have the same problem, but 'break' still stops it comparing values when it's already found a match.

Answer (score 0):

There is also problem with variables passed inside $_POST[]. In html, you have given name with first letter capital as **Username** & **Password**. But passing wrong in $_POST. Please check.

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
```

This should be

```
$username = $_POST["Username"];
$password = $_POST["Password"];
```

Also you need to include break inside foreach.